# jQuery .find() error: "Unexpected call to method or property access"

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm having some problems with getting one of my site pages with IE8. It works fine in IE9, Safari (both PC & Mac) & Firefox (Mac). I'm using a `find(tag1).html(tag1)` call sequence to do a title substitution, but I get the following error in IE8 when I debug it in the IE script debugger, and this in the `html(tag2)` function:

> Unexpected call to method or property access

The `find(tag1)` function seems to return the enclosing object (i.e. `#sidebar`), rather than the nested object `#sidebarheader`, and this causes problems when later making the `html(tag2)` call.

I've created a representative test case as follows:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>JQuery .find() test case</title> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript">
        function UpdateHeader() { 
           $('#sidebar').find('header').html("New Title"); // IE8, nesting div's in the find fct. will not discover the child div
        }

        document.ready = UpdateHeader;
    </script>
</head>

<body>
      <div style="height: 400px; width: 390px">

          <div id="jqm-home">
            <div id="page">
                <div id="sidebar">
                    <div id="sidebarheader">
                        <header>Old Title</header>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          <p onclick="UpdateHeader();">Click to update title</p>   
          </div>
      </div>     
</body>            
</html>
```

And here is the jsFiddle test case:

http://jsfiddle.net/bnmcK/21/

Has anybody a suggestion on how to get this to work in IE8?

Answer (score 4):

In order to support the new HTML 5 elements in older versions of IE (8 and below), there's a handy trick, which involves creating a dummy element before running your script.

So, simply calling `document.createElement('header');` in your page will solve the problem, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sz4Sb/2/).

For the full explanation, [this post](http://blog.whatwg.org/supporting-new-elements-in-ie) does a nice job of providing an explanation.

Also, [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) is a project that solves this problem for other elements too.

Answer (score 1):

<header> is a HTML5 tag, which IE8 doesn't know about (IE9 however, supports this tag). Since you're declaring XHTML 1.0 transitional, I'd suggest using a <h1> tag instead, which will work just fine in IE8.